# sd_bus_get_property_string equivalent for gdbus?

Tags: properties, systemd, gdbus

I try to read out the `ActiveState` property of a *systemd unit* with `gdbus`/`glib-2.0`. For *sd-bus* there exists the convenient function `sd_bus_get_property_string`. What would the equivalent call if *gdbus* is used. I am ware of the `gdbus introspect` command, but I need to implement that in C/C++.

I managed to start and stop units already. Now I need to verify that a unit has been successful started/stopped. I am new to dbus and have been searching the internet for some hours for an example, without finding something helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I also implemented some systemd stuff in C++.  Here was my solution:

```
std::string Unit::GetPropertyString(const std::string& property) const
{
    sd_bus_error err = SD_BUS_ERROR_NULL;
    char* msg = nullptr;
    int r;

    r = sd_bus_get_property_string(m_bus,
        "org.freedesktop.systemd1",
        ("/org/freedesktop/systemd1/unit/" + m_unit).c_str(),
        "org.freedesktop.systemd1.Unit",
        property.c_str(),
        &err,
        &msg);

    if (r < 0)
    {
        std::string err_msg(err.message);
        sd_bus_error_free(&err);

        std::string err_str("Failed to get " + property + " for service "
                            + m_name + ". Error: " + err_msg);

        throw slib_exception(err_str);
    }

    sd_bus_error_free(&err);

    // Free memory (avoid leaking)
    std::string ret(msg);
    free (msg);

    return ret;
}
```

From this, you can call

```
activestate = GetPropertyString("ActiveState");
substate = GetPropertyString("SubState");
```

I found that a lot of the `<systemd/sd-bus.h>` wasn't well documented.  There is a fantastic explanation by the author here: 
http://0pointer.net/blog/the-new-sd-bus-api-of-systemd.html

But outside of the few examples he gives, I found it was easier to inspect the source code.  Specifically, I found it nice looking into the source-code of the `systemctl` and `journalctl` applications to see how `sd-bus` was used in those contexts.